# sx prop not applying calc() function

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to apply `margin` to `<Typography>`, but it's not getting applied.
`calc(100vw-100px)` is not working and in DOM it's not applied. what's the issue?

// App.js

```js
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Box>
      {/* calc() is not applying in DOM */}
      <Typography sx={{ ml: `calc(100vw-100px)` }}>Hello World!</Typography>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/calc-not-working-with-sx-prop-sofl-6rphzn) Demo

Comment: Can you try with a space before and after "-" in your calc ?

Comment: Yes, with space given , it's working.